# ストア アプリとは何ですか?

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps

Windows 8 から、以下で示すようにアプリの種類がたくさん出てきました。

- ストア アプリ
- Windows Runtime アプリ
- Windows Phone ストア アプリ
- Windows ストア アプリ
- ユニバーサル Windows アプリ

それぞれ、どういう意味で、どのような違いがあるのでしょうか?

Answer (score 6):

2014年12月現在、Microsoft の用語としては以下のようになっています。  
※ Windows 10 では、Xbox もユニバーサル Windows アプリの対象になるといわれており、その際には用語も変更される可能性があります。  
※ 2014年12月30日編集: 12月19日から本日までの間に、日本語版 MSDN のページが英語版に合わせて変更されました。それに合わせて、「ストア アプリ」を「Windows ランタイム アプリ」に修正します。

日本語版 MSDN: [<del>ストア アプリ</del>Windows ランタイム アプリとは](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/apps/dn726767.aspx)  
英語版 MSDN: [What's a Windows Runtime app?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn726767.aspx)

- 「<del>ストア アプリ</del>Windows ランタイム アプリ」(日) / 「Windows Runtime app」(米)  
  Windows デバイスと Windows Phone で動作する、デスクトップ アプリ以外のアプリ  
  であって、Windows ランタイムを使うもの
- 「Windows ストア アプリ」 / 「Windows Store apps」  
  <del>ストア アプリ</del>Windows ランタイム アプリ / Windows Runtime app であって、Windows デバイス (PC、タブレット、ノート PC など) 上で動作し、Windows ストアで販売できるもの
- 「Windows Phone ストア アプリ」 / 「Windows Phone Store apps」  
  <del>ストア アプリ</del>Windows ランタイム アプリ / Windows Runtime app であって、Windows Phone 上で動作し、Windows Phone ストアで販売できるもの
- 「ユニバーサル Windows アプリ」 / 「universal Windows app」  
  <del>ストア アプリ</del>Windows ランタイム アプリ / Windows Runtime app であって、Windows ストアと Windows Phone ストアの両方で入手できるアプリ  
  ※ 「ユニバーサル Windows」のアプリではなく、ユニバーサルな「Windows アプリ」。その意を強調するためか、英語では先頭の「u」が小文字で表記されることがある。

[image: ストアアプリの関係]

※ 2014年12月30日追記  
「ストア アプリ」→「Windows ランタイム アプリ」への用語変更にともない、次の種類のアプリが包含されなくなりました。なお、この定義に従うと、Windows Phone Silverlight X アプリと Windows ストア アプリをユニバーサル化した場合(可能です。筆者もやりましたし、MS 謹製アプリにもあります)、それらをユニバーサル Windows アプリとは呼べなくなります。

- 「Windows Phone Silverlight アプリ」(Windows Phone 7.x 用)・「Windows Phone Silverlight 8 アプリ」・「Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 アプリ」  
  Windows Phone 上で動作し、Windows Phone ストアで販売できるアプリだが、Windows ランタイム アプリではないもの

Comment: 細かいことを言えば、英語版では Windows Runtime を使うアプリに限定されていて、日本語版ではそうでないものも含んでいます。
英語版の定義に従うと、Windows Phone 7.x 向けのアプリや、Windows Phone 8.x 向けであっても Windows Runtime を使っていないアプリが、「Windows Phone Store apps」に含まれていないことになります。

Answer (score 1):

ざっくり書くと以下のようになります

- ストア アプリ・・・・Windows Phone ストア アプリ と Windows Storeアプリ を一括りにした用語
- Windows Phone ストア アプリ・・・・WindowsPhone7/8.1のみで動作するアプリ(スマホ要素が強い)
- Windows Storeアプリ・・・・Windows8/8.1/のみで動作するアプリ(タブレット要素が強い)
- ユニバーサルアプリ・・・・Windows Phone と Windows8/8.1 の両方でダウンロード＆起動が可能なアプリ
  (もちろん開発も両方可能)